# Sympy gives unexpected differentiation result when the input is a string

Tags: sympy

Why is the result of the differentiation not `2*x0` in the following code:

```
In [54]: import sympy

In [55]: x = [sympy.Symbol('x%d' % i, real=True) for i in range(3)]

In [56]: x
Out[56]: [x0, x1, x2]

In [57]: sympy.diff('x0*x0 + x1*x1 + x2*x2',x[0])
Out[57]: 0
```

Comment: Probably because a string is treated as a constant.

Comment: [No "_Thanks"_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the creation of multiple numbered symbols is simpler with

```
x = sympy.symbols('x0:3', real=True)     # returns (x0, x1, x2)
```

Second, the SymPy function to turn a string into a SymPy expression is [`sympify`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.sympify.sympify). This function is called automatically when you provide input as a string; however, this gives you no control over the interpretation of the string, and "unexpected results" are likely.

In this case, SymPy is not sure that "x0" appearing in the string is the same as x0 you created earlier. After all, your x0 has the additional property of being real, and the symbol from the string has no such assumptions on it. It's `Symbol('x0')` vs `Symbol('x0', real=True)`; not a  match.

This is one of many reasons why throwing a string in a SymPy function is a bad idea. Use `sympify`, and read about its parameters which control the parsing of input. Specifically, `locals` parameter is a dictionary mapping pieces of the string to objects you already have in SymPy, precisely what is needed here.

```
locals = {'x{}'.format(i): x[i] for i in range(3)}  #  {'x0': x0, 'x1': x1, 'x2': x2}
expr = sympy.sympify('x0*x0 + x1*x1 + x2*x2', locals=locals)
```

Now you can differentiate expr with respect to any symbols and get expected results

```
[expr.diff(sym) for sym in x]   #  [2*x0, 2*x1, 2*x2]
```

(Another benefit of having an expression before trying `diff` is that you can invoke `diff` as a method of the expression, saving the trouble of typing `sympy.` prefix.)

Answer (score 1):

In your declarations, you should use `sympy.symbols` that is the reference method (from the documentation and tutorial) to declare variables.

```
x = [sympy.symbols('x%d' % i, real=True) for i in range(3)]
```

On top of this, you must pick (from experimentations that I made) either a string in both arguments, as:

```
sympy.diff('x0*x0 + x1*x1 + x2*x2',str(x[0]))
```

or symbolic expressions on both sides:

```
sympy.diff(x[0]*x[0] + x[1]*x[1] + x[2]*x[2], x[0])
```

Comment: That works, thank you. Would you happen to know a way to symbolify a string?

Comment: no, but sympy as documentation about "parsing" :-) If you wish to know more (and if it is not found easily in the docs), it would be best to open a dedicated question